# How Can I add an Object so that is not facing the current the view?

Tags: 3d-view

I was following a tutorial on blender ( I dont remember which now, as I have watched a lot ). I some how  set up this feature and now I dont know how to turn it off.

Each time I apply an object in to my scene, it applies facing whichever direction my camera is facing. How can I get this back to the default of applying the object in the center?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the bottom left of your picture. See a box that reads Align to View?

[image]

Disable it

Comment: You can change the default for this setting in preferences under the editing tab.